# Save image with background as transparent in pyglet

Tags: python, pyglet, pymunk

After some actions in my simple pyglet app I want to record the scene into a png image
that includes transparency.
I have set `pyglet.gl.glClearColor(0,0,0,0)` In an attempt to make the background transparent. The scene is only consisted of sprite objects and the background. To record the current Image I am using the following snippet

```
pyglet.image.get_buffer_manager().get_color_buffer().save(filename)
```

The problem with this approach though is that the alpha channel is not stored in the png. Is there a way to capture the image without the background? If so would I be able to capture each sprite separately in a png with a transparency channel?

Attempt at a minimum reproducible example:

```
import pymunk.pygame_util
import pymunk
from pymunk import Vec2d, BB
import pymunk.pygame_util
import pymunk.autogeometry
import numpy as np
import pyglet
import math
import random
import pymunk.pyglet_util
from pyglet.gl import *
HOME_DIR = "this is the home directory path"
class myPygletGame(pyglet.window.Window):
    draw_options = pymunk.pyglet_util.DrawOptions()
    pyglet.gl.glClearColor(0,0,0,0)
    width = 1000
    height = 1000
    space = pymunk.Space()
    space.gravity = 0, -600
    batch = pyglet.graphics.Batch()
    def __init__(self):
        super(myPygletGame, self).__init__()
        self.set_size(self.width, self.height)
        pyglet.clock.schedule_interval(self.update, 1/60)
        pyglet.clock.schedule_once(self.spawn_logo1, 1)
        pyglet.app.run()
    def on_draw(self,):
        pyglet.gl.glClearColor(0,0,0,0)
        self.clear()
        self.render()
        self.batch.draw()
    def render(self):
        glClearColor(  0, 0,   0, 0)  # background color
        glEnable(GL_LINE_SMOOTH)
        glEnable(GL_BLEND)                                  # transparency
        glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA)   # transparency
    def update(self,dt):
        dt = 1.0/60. #override dt to keep physics simulation stable
        self.space.step(dt)
    def spawn_logo1(self,dt):
        pyglet.gl.glClearColor(0,0,0,0)
        self.Mycar = Car(self)
        self.save_a_frame()
    def save_a_frame(self):
        filename=" frame-sec.png"
        pyglet.image.get_buffer_manager().get_color_buffer().save(HOME_DIR + filename)

class Car():
    def __init__(self, WindowGameRef):
        self.WindowGameRef = WindowGameRef
        self.imagePath = "imageSprite.png"
        b = pymunk.Body(mass=1, moment=10000)
        shape = pymunk.Segment(b,  [100,100],  [200,200], 2)
        WindowGameRef.space.add(shape , b) 
        pyglet.resource.path = [HOME_DIR]
        pyglet.resource.reindex()
        self.logo_img = pyglet.resource.image(self.imagePath)
        self.sprite = pyglet.sprite.Sprite(self.logo_img, batch=self.WindowGameRef.batch)
        self.sprite.position = b.position

if __name__ == "__main__":
    mygame = myPygletGame()
```

Comment: What does `pyglet.image.get_buffer_manager().get_color_buffer().format` say?

Comment: 'RGBA' although the output png doesnot have the 'A' channel

Comment: That's odd, may I ask how you verify that it doesn't have an alpha channel? other than not seeing transparent parts of your image that is.

Comment: You are right! I just checked with opencv and there is an alpha channel, but the value of all of the pixels is 255.

Comment: Sweet, then I might have an idea. Could you post a minimal example of code that we could execute? ~15 lines or something that we can execute that reproduces the issue.

Comment: I should have posted one from the start, not 15 lines but I tried to remove everything extra.. Should just be the sprite+pymunk body and the background.

Comment: Did you manage to figure out what is wrong with my code regarding the background? @Torxed

Comment: What version of pyglet do you use, and what OS do you run? I tried running the latest (1.5.7), and there I only get a transparent image without any content both for your example, and my own code that I know have worked with previous versions.

Comment: Sorry for the really late reply. However what i did to solve this, if i remember correctly, was to create the background mask separately from the sprite/objects by coloring the objects as white and the background as black (to extract later by threshold). If I get a chance I will come back to this with the version, os was windows.